# Is there an IntelliJ equivalent of Resharper's Value Origin/Destination?

Tags: java, c#, intellij-idea, resharper

After a long time with Resharper in C#, I'm now in Java land with IntelliJ. Occasionally I found the Resharper feature of [Value Origin / Destination](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__Value_Tracking.html) really useful. Is there an equivalent in IntelliJ? I can't seem to find it.

For anyone not familiar with the Resharper feature, it gives you the ability to trace the hierarchy of sources/destinations for a variable/field's value. So you can trace where a parameter's value comes from across the call stack, across copying from other variables, return values from functions, etc. Or similarly trace where a parameters value goes to.

Jetbrains's Resharper example:

[image: Value origin example]

Comment: [Analyze Data Flow to Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/analyzing-data-flow.html#r_Analyzing_Data_Flow.xmld14078e121)?

Comment: Yeah I just found that, it's what I was looking for. Want to submit a quick answer and I'll accept? Could be useful for other people, as googling for this was just giving results about Resharper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IntelliJ IDEA this feature is called [Analyze Data Flow to Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/analyzing-data-flow.html#r_Analyzing_Data_Flow.xmld14078e121).